::error::Ensure GITHUB_TOKEN has permission "id-token: write"
I am having the same problem as GitHub Actions - Unable to get ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL env variable, but only when running act locally.
My deploy.yml file (which has the added write permissions) is:
name: Deploy Frontend

on:
  push:
    branches: [main, staging, frontend]
    paths:
      - 'frontend/**'
      - '.github/workflows/deploy_frontend.yml'
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
      pages: write       # Added for GitHub Pages deployment
      id-token: write    # Necessary for actions/deploy-pages
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Debug REACT_APP_API_URL
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo -e "\e[32m@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\e[0m"
        echo -e "\e[32mREACT_APP_API_URL=${REACT_APP_API_URL}\e[0m"
        env
        echo $(env | grep ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN)
        # exit 1  # Commented out to allow the workflow to continue

    - name: Set up Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v4
      with:
        node-version: '20'

    - name: Print Environment Variables and Secrets
      shell: bash
      env:
        REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT: ${{ env.REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT }}
      run: |
        echo -e "\e[32mREACT_APP_API_URL=${REACT_APP_API_URL}\e[0m"
        echo -e "\e[32mREACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=${REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT}\e[0m"
        env
        echo ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN=$(env | grep ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN)

    - name: Install dependencies
      shell: bash
      run: |
        cd frontend
        npm ci 2>&1 || (echo -e "\e[31mInstall dependencies step failed.\e[0m" && exit 1)

    - name: Build
      shell: bash
      run: |
        npm install env-cmd or npm install -g env-cmd
        cd frontend
        mkdir -p build_logs
        TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        export REACT_APP_BUILD_TIME=$(TZ=America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        echo -e "\e[32mBuilding with environment variables:\e[0m"
        env
        echo -e "\e[32m$(pwd)\e[0m"
        npm run build || (echo -e "\e[31mBuild step failed.\e[0m" && exit 1)

    - name: Setup Pages
      uses: actions/configure-pages@v4

    - name: Upload artifact
      uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v3
      with:
        path: './frontend/build'

    - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
      id: deployment
      uses: actions/deploy-pages@v4

    - name: Build Succeeded
      if: success()
      run: echo -e "\e[32mBuild succeeded.\e[0m"

    - name: Build Failed
      if: failure()
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo -e "\e[31mBuild failed.\e[0m"
        exit 1


and I am running act like so:
act -j build-and-deploy -W .github/workflows/deploy_frontend.yml --secret-file /home/noams/src/personal_website/frontend/.secrets_frontend --env-file /home/noams/src/personal_website/frontend/.env --artifact-server-path /tmp/artifacts

The error:
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]   ✅  Success - Main Upload artifact
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]   ⚙  ::set-output:: artifact-id=1
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]   ⚙  ::set-output:: artifact-url=https://github.com/***/actions/runs/1/artifacts/1
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]   ⚙  ::set-output:: artifact_id=1
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]   ✅  Success - Main Upload artifact
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]   ⚙  ::set-output:: artifact-url=https://github.com/***/actions/runs/1/artifacts/1
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]   ⚙  ::set-output:: artifact-id=1
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy] ⭐ Run Main Deploy to GitHub Pages
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]     docker cp src=/home/noams/.cache/act/actions-deploy-pages@v4/ dst=/var/run/act/actions/actions-deploy-pages@v4/
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]     docker exec cmd=[/opt/acttoolcache/node/18.20.4/x64/bin/node /var/run/act/actions/actions-deploy-pages@v4/dist/index.js] user= workdir=
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]     ::debug::all variables are set
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]     ::debug::all variables are set
| Error: Error message: Unable to get ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL env variable
|     at Function.<anonymous> (/run/act/actions/actions-deploy-pages@v4/node_modules/@actions/core/lib/oidc-utils.js:71:1)
|     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
|     at /run/act/actions/actions-deploy-pages@v4/node_modules/@actions/core/lib/oidc-utils.js:8:1
|     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
|     at __webpack_modules__.98041.__awaiter (/run/act/actions/actions-deploy-pages@v4/node_modules/@actions/core/lib/oidc-utils.js:4:1)
|     at Function.getIDToken (/run/act/actions/actions-deploy-pages@v4/node_modules/@actions/core/lib/oidc-utils.js:57:1)
|     at Object.<anonymous> (/run/act/actions/actions-deploy-pages@v4/node_modules/@actions/core/lib/core.js:315:1)
|     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
|     at /run/act/actions/actions-deploy-pages@v4/node_modules/@actions/core/lib/core.js:27:1
|     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]   ❗  ::error::Ensure GITHUB_TOKEN has permission "id-token: write".
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]   ❌  Failure - Main Deploy to GitHub Pages
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy] exitcode '1': failure
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy] ⭐ Run Main Build Failed
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]     docker exec cmd=[bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail /var/run/act/workflow/10.sh] user= workdir=
| Build failed.
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]   ❌  Failure - Main Build Failed
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy] exitcode '1': failure
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy] ⭐ Run Post Upload artifact
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]     docker cp src=/home/noams/.cache/act/actions-upload-pages-artifact@v3/ dst=/var/run/act/actions/actions-upload-pages-artifact@v3/
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]   ✅  Success - Post Upload artifact
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]   Job failed
Error: Job 'build-and-deploy' failed

This error does not happen in GitHub Actions, only locally with act.
How to make act play nice with this token, which is fed in correctly in the .secrets file?

The issue you're running into is due to how act handles OIDC tokens, particularly the id-token: write permission. Unfortunately, act doesn’t fully support all GitHub Actions features, and it seems like OIDC token functionality is one of them. Since the token is required for authentication in actions/deploy-pages@v4, you'll see this error locally but not when running it directly on GitHub Actions.
In my opinion, if you need to use the secret but want to skip the part that causes problems with act, you can add a condition to bypass the deployment step locally. Something like:
- name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
  if: ${{ !env.ACT }}
  id: deployment
  uses: actions/deploy-pages@v4

This ensures that the deployment step, which requires the OIDC token, only runs on GitHub Actions and not in your local environment. That way, other steps that use your secrets will still execute normally.
For instance, as you’re using a secret like REACT_APP_API_URL in your workflow, you should be able to access it like this:
- name: Debug REACT_APP_API_URL
  shell: bash
  run: |
    echo "REACT_APP_API_URL=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_API_URL }}"

As long as the secret is defined in your .secrets_frontend file, act will handle it, and everything except the OIDC-dependent step should run as expected.
I hope this helps provide some direction.

This only provides a way to not accomplish my task of making this work locally. If there is a way to work around this, it would be nice, but as it is, if(local): fail silently is what I already have, without the silence (which is better)

Got it. Hmm, I don’t think there’s more options. I might be wrong, so it’ll be nice if someone else has other ideas.
